# Azure Batch: Do I get charged after deleting job but still keep pool?

Tags: azure-batch

I found it takes a few minutes to create pool and prepare the job, I am thinking to keep the pool to get rid of the overhead.

Thanks
Lidong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can try and answer this but folks can correct me, AFAIK: refer to this document: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/batch/

In batch as doc states: “Virtual machines are billed per-second rounded down to the last minute.”

Most of the pricing structure is well document and seems like it’s just few cents per hour.

One general suggestion could be that once you are done with your compute you can always re-scale your pool back to 0.

You probably want to add more to your question if you are keen to discuss any specific scenario so that right folks can answer in detail.

Hope this helps, but add more most o the content above is general purpose. Thanks

**Update** https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/

[image]

Comment: I am still not clear if I keep the pool after job finish and not re-scale to 0, will the VM in pool still running, do I get charged on that?

Comment: @lidong VM in "Idle" state is VM in use. I think if you keep the VM around in Idle state then AFAIK you will get charged for the VM time, i.e. the VM's will get bill it not doing anything, in the mean time why not try out the "Calculator" to check, Also **rescaling** to 0 node will allow you to keep the pool and wont charge anything IMO.

Comment: @lidong (Updated the post as well) I checked and what mentioned above is right: also refere to this link :https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/ at the bottom of the page it reiterate same thing.